# How to feed GNU Parallel with an array containing new lines?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I would like to run a script for every entry of an array which stores file names containing white spaces (including new lines). How to send such an entry to the script using GNU Parallel?

In addition, can the script obtain two arguments - its sequence number and the file name?

Comment: Well, there's not much to commenton, really.
The `parallel` command should run a script in this manner:
`./script_name <sequence_number> "file name with
new lines"` where the file name is one element of shell (Bash) variable `files`.

Answer (score 2):

---

The solution is to use the GNU Parallel's `--null` switch (or its alias `-0`) which tells it to use the NULL delimiter instead of new line. This way, arrays with elements containing new lines can be passed to GNU Parallel e.g. like this:

```
parallel --gnu --null "command_to_be_executed" "{}" ::: "${array[@]}"
```

If you also want the command to obtain its sequence number, precede `"{}"` with `{#}`.

If you are trying to use this command to process some files whose names (or paths leading to them) may contain new lines, here is an example of how `array` could be constructed (new-line safe):

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    files+=("$file")
done < <(`find "/path/to/files/" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -print0"`)
```